# Layout and local.xml

Tags: layout

using Alans Storms layout viewer I have the following:

```
<reference name="my.account.wrapper">
<block type="sales/order_history" name="sales.order.history">
<block type="core/text_list" name="sales.order.history.info" as="info" translate="label">
<label>Order History Info</label>
</block>
</block>
<block type="customer/account_dashboard" name="customer.account.link.back" template="customer/account/link/back.phtml"/>
</reference>

<reference name="my.account.wrapper">
<remove item="customer.account.link.back"/>
</reference>
```

.....

the last three lines being those added by my local xml...

```
<sales_order_history>

  <reference name="my.account.wrapper">
    <remove item="customer.account.link.back" />
  </reference>

</sales_order_history>
```

Can anyone tell me why the back link block is not being removed?

Thanks in advance, Richard.

Comment: And you don't need a reference here. `<remove>` uses the globally unique name of the block, not the alias which is only unique in the child context (like unsetChild) uses it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The remove tag works with a `name` attribute

```
<remove item="customer.account.link.back" />
```

should be

```
<remove name="customer.account.link.back" />
```